# Benefit of running command-line PHP with the "-f" argument

Tags: php, shell, command-line-interface

I have been trying to figure out why some of my shell scripts alternate between using the parser option. Some list the PHP command like this:

```
php -f indexer.php
```

While other just use:

```
php indexer.php
```

I did a series of tests trying to see if the results varied based on PHP functionality but I haven't been able to see a difference.

The documentation states "*The **-f** is optional and may be omitted - providing just the filename to execute is sufficient.*"

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

So when would you use it?

Comment: Since it is optional I would never use it since it provides no benefit. It is a hold-over from earlier command line implementations.

Comment: It's PHP. Do not ask deep philosophical questions of it. You'll be the saner for it.

Answer (score 1):

About the only useful purpose for `-f` is to explicitly indicate which of the command line args is the script to be executed:

```
php foo.php bar.php
```

While PHP would execute the FIRST filename encountered on the command line and leave the rest as arguments for that first script, putting it as

```
php -f foo.php bar.php
```

makes it that wee little bit more obvious.

Comment: What about when it is using an action? e.g. php -f indexer.php reindexall

Comment: same thing. using `.php` as an extension is merely a convention. just like shell scripts don't have to be `foo.sh`, a php script doesn't have to be `foo.php`. `mv foo.php foo; php foo` will STILL execute it